# How to hide a div with direction and duration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the code below. Why am I not able to hide the `#legend`
div by this way?

```
$("#icon").on("click",function(){
   $("#legend").hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
});
```

I also tried the animation way but it didn't work either.

[image]

Comment: I _believe_ the slide effect is part of the jquery-ui. Just wanted to make sure you had the right libraries. Also, can you confirm the `on('click')` event is firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have used the syntax wrongly.. Just try like,

```
$(selector).hide(speed,easing,callback);
```

Please refer the jQuery document [**here**](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)...

I have updated a [**fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/soundar24/anLwW/) here... Please check this..

**Hint:** Here callback is a function which is executed after the animation completes. But it is not mandatory.. you can also leave this parameter..

Updated a [**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/G4hB9/6/) with jQuery UI animation...

Comment: Hi Spunder can you please let me know what should I use for callback?

Comment: great just one last question, is there any way to hide object from left to right I mean not from lower left to upper right?

Comment: I think you need like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/G4hB9/6/)... To use this you need jQuery UI..

Comment: yeah but I didn't really want to use the jQuery Ui, Cant' pure jQurey do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `animate()` method for that,

```
$('#legend').animate({width: '0'}, 1000, function(){
 $(this).hide();
});
```

Check the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FyvdL/7/).

Comment: Hi Anoop, thanks alot for reply but can you please take a look ath this fiddle result "http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/52VtD/4056/embedded/result/" and let me know how I can deal with stacking the other div at the animate time on top of each other? if you click on green div (icon) it starts animation but the other components stacks on top of each other!

Comment: stacking means? can you explain more?

Comment: sorry I mean they appeas on the top of each other(icon, title, and cart) untill to be hidden

Comment: if you take a look at very left end you will notice this

Comment: you want it side by side?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but I want to just hide the whole "legend" div in one row, why they sit on the top each other before hiding?

Comment: Ca you please take a look at updated image? I just capture this before adding the title at bottom.